# Java Error unreachable statement

Tags: java, object, return, unreachable-statement

Im trying to create a class that has a base object. The base object will be used to create a few objects and be made to 'fight' in another class based on strength and powerups.

I have got this error when compiling 'Error, unreachable statement' and it points to line 27 pointing to the return, can someone help me out please?

```
public class Superhero {

    private String superheroName;
    private int superheroStrength;
    public int powerUp;

    public Superhero (String superheroName, int superheroStrength, int powerUp){
    this.superheroName = superheroName;
    this.superheroStrength = superheroStrength;
    System.out.println("Superhero: " + superheroName);
    System.out.println("Strength: " + ( superheroStrength + powerUp));
    }

    public Superhero (String superheroName, int powerUp){
    this.superheroName = superheroName;
    superheroStrength = 10;
    System.out.println("Strength: " + ( superheroStrength+powerUp));
    }

    public int getStrength(){
        return superheroStrength += powerUp;
    }

    public void powerUp (int powerUp){
        this.powerUp += powerUp;
    }

    public Superhero  battle(Superhero1 opponent){
        if (this.getStrength()>opponent.getStrength());
        return this;
        return opponent;
    }
    public String toString(){
    return this.superheroName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove the `;` at the end of this line : `if (this.getStrength()>opponent.getStrength());`

Comment: Alternatively, replace the aforementioned `;` with `{}` and put `return this;` in the block. This will make it more readable, solve the unreachability problem, and make it more obvious because right now it isn't even indented.

Comment: This is one of the reasons why you should always use curly brackets for `if` statements, even if they only contain a single statement.

Comment: @JonK It's equally possible to make the same mistake even if you have curly brackets.

Answer (score 1):

An extra `;` caused all the mess

```
if (this.getStrength()>opponent.getStrength()); <--
```

That semicolon terminates the statement there ,And assuming it as a new block stating from there.

Hence the code

```
public Superhero  battle(Superhero1 opponent){
    if (this.getStrength()>opponent.getStrength());
    return this;
    return opponent;
}
```

equals to

```
public Superhero  battle(Superhero1 opponent){
    if (this.getStrength()>opponent.getStrength()){
    }
    return this;
    return opponent;
}
```

Remove that extra `;` (*hope that is not intentionally typed*), codes will be fine then.

As someone commented already, that's the reason, use always curly braces to avoid situations like this.